# smallest subfield contains open interval

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

$\mathbb Q(A) $ means the smallest subfield that contains $\mathbb Q\cup A$ where $A\subset\mathbb R.$ My question is:   Let $I$ be  an open interval subset of $\mathbb R.$ If $I\subset \mathbb Q(A)$ then $\mathbb R\subset\mathbb Q(A).$ Is it true ? I think yes, because since $\mathbb Q(A)$ is filed.

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Q}(A)$ contains all rational translates of $I$. Show that for $a\lt b$, the rational translates $(a+q,b+q)$, $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, covers $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Arturo, Thank you. This means the answer for my question is true. The subfield will cover the whole $\mathbb R$. right?

Comment: If you can prove it, yes.

Comment: Arturo Magidin, I have one more question related to this. The cardinality of $\mathbb Q(A)$ is equal to $\omega+|A|$. Right?

Comment: $\omega$ is usually an ordinal, not a cardinal. Any open interval has cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|=\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$, so $\mathbb{Q}(A)$ has that cardinality as well, as it can’t have any larger cardinality. But cardinality arguments will not get you anywhere: there are plenty of proper subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I might not state my question clearly. I meant in general, let $B\subset\mathbb Q$. So, the cardinality of $\mathbb Q(B)$ equals to $\aleph_0+|B|$. Right?

Comment: If $B\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$, then it is countable, so $\mathbb{Q}(B)$ is also countable: cardinality $\aleph_0$. If you meant $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then yes, you get the largest of $\aleph_0$ and $|B|$, which is the same as their sum. And, as I mentioned already, all of this is almost certainly utterly useless to you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Thank you so much for your explanation.